# What is the use of CELL_TYPE_ERROR?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to understand the use of cell type CELL_TYPE_ERROR in apache poi. I tried the following code, I see no error.

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Row row = sheet1.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR);
cell.setCellValue(234);
System.out.println("error cell value-"+ cell.getNumericCellValue()); //this prints 234.0
```

Also, I want to understand if the cell can be of type `error` if we don't manually set its type.

Comment: Did you try writing the workbook to a file and open it with Excel or Libre-/ OpenOffice? My guess is that if at all, setting the cell type to error manually would be visible there. Other than that, I think the purpose is that you can programmatically check for computation errors. E.g., if you have an excel sheet with a cell with the formula =6/0, then this cell should be a formula cell. If you then copy this cell and paste its value, you should have a error cell (any other cell type should not be applicable here.

Comment: I tried writing the workbook to a file with an error cell and opened it using excel. The error cell does not cause any issue there. Also, i created a formula `= 1/0` and copied the cell, the newly created cell type is again formula.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the comments in the code.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

class CellTypeErrorTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

  //The following works, but it makes no sense, because the cell will have no real content.
  //If you wants to see, how this will be shown into the Workbook, then comment out the
  //following code that overwrites the Cell with numeric content.
  cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR);
  cell.setCellErrorValue(FormulaError.DIV0.getCode());
  System.out.println("error cell value-"+ FormulaError.forInt(cell.getErrorCellValue()).getString());

  //If you put real content in the cell, then the CELL_TYPE_ERROR goes away, if the content 
  //not produces ERROR.
  cell.setCellValue(234);
  System.out.println(cell.getCellType()); //0 == CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC

  //If you put a Formula in the Cell, it will not be evaluated automatically.
  //So there is no error, even the formula will produce error if it will be evaluated.
  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellFormula("1/0");
  System.out.println(cell.getCellType()); //2 == CELL_TYPE_FORMULA

  //It you need to check if a formula produces error, then you have to evaluate it.
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
  CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
  System.out.println(cellValue.getCellType()); //5 == CELL_TYPE_ERROR
  if (cellValue.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR) {
   System.out.println("error cell value-"+ FormulaError.forInt(cellValue.getErrorValue()).getString());
  }

  try {
   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }

 }
}
```

Conclusion:

The Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR is necessary to detect if a cell content produces an error.  It mostly makes no sense, to set it manually.

It can be setted manually to cells without real content with cell.setCellErrorValue. But this mostly makes no sense, because if the cell gets real content and this don't produces an error, then the CellType changes automatically to another type.

POI do not evaluate the cells formulas automatically. CellTypes of cells with formulas are ever Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA. Therefore, to check whether a cell formula produces error, we have to evaluate manually and then to check the CellType of the evaluated CellValue. See: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, If I understand correctly, a cell type is an error only if we set its type to 'ERROR' manually and in few cases where we evaluate the formula that produces an error. Also, For workbooks that are not created using POI, does this cell type have any significance? I think this cell type is useful only in the context of apche poi api.

Comment: Hm, no my conclusion is contrary to your's. I've written my conclusion into my answer now.